# Why does my Perlin Noise Terrain have rough parts on the edges?

Tags: unity, perlin-noise

I followed this tutorial: https://gamedevacademy.org/complete-guide-to-procedural-level-generation-in-unity-part-1/

The important bits of my code are below. I tried messing around with different parameters for a while, and I'm not sure how to fix the noticeable lines between tiles.

```
void GenerateTile()
    {
        Vector3[] meshVertices = this.meshFilter.mesh.vertices;
        int tileDepth = (int) Mathf.Sqrt(meshVertices.Length);
        int tileWidth = tileDepth;
        
        // calc heightmap
        float[,] heightMap = this.noiseMapGenerator.GenerateNoiseMap(tileDepth, tileWidth, this.mapScale, -this.transform.position.x, -this.transform.position.z, waves);
        
        // update texture and mesh
        Texture2D tileTexture = BuildTexture(heightMap);
        this.tileRenderer.material.mainTexture = tileTexture;
        UpdateMeshVertices(heightMap);
    }
```

```
public float[,] GenerateNoiseMap(int mapDepth, int mapWidth, float scale, float offsetX, float offsetZ, Wave[] waves)
    {
        // Instantiate noiseMap
        float[,] noiseMap = new float[mapDepth, mapWidth];

        // Populate noiseMap
        for (int zidx = 0; zidx < mapDepth; zidx ++)
        {
            for (int xidx = 0; xidx < mapDepth; xidx ++)
            {
                float noise = 0f;
                float norm = 0f;
                float x_val = (xidx + offsetX)  / scale;
                float z_val = (zidx + offsetZ) / scale;
                
                // Layer multiple waves on top of each other
                foreach (Wave wave in waves)
                {
                    noise += wave.amplitude * Mathf.PerlinNoise( (x_val * wave.frequency + wave.seed), (z_val * wave.frequency + wave.seed));
                    norm += wave.amplitude;
                }
                
                // Normalize and assign
                noise /= norm;
                noiseMap[zidx, xidx] = noise;
            }
        }
        return noiseMap;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried making your meshes 1 unit larger than you are tiling? Because these lines are a result of mismatched normals between the meshes. Basically, the end of one mesh has no idea how the next continues and therefore has no idea how to catch the light properly.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your suggestion. Could you please elaborate? I'm recalculating normals when updating the mesh, if that's of any help.

Comment: Okay, say for example every mesh is 10 x 10 units, right? So each runs from 0-9 on both axis. The vertex at (0,10) in the 0,0 mesh has no idea about the height at (0,11), so it has to guess at the normal vector at that vertex. Meanwhile, the overlapping (0,10) vertex in the 0,1 mesh DOES have that information, so it can build the normal vector properly (even though it itself is missing data about (0,9)). Because those normal vectors differ, the lighting suddenly shifts, creating those edges.

Comment: Oh so are you saying to overlap the tiles by one unit?

Comment: Or you could compute normals from your noise function and assign them to each vertex, so the vertices that meet along an edge agree on their normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this, Unity's Mathf.PerlinNoise is symmetrical. That seems to be the root of your problem. https://forum.unity.com/threads/perlin-noise-symmetrical.390981/

That's not the only reason I wouldn't use it though. Perlin noise in general tends to generate a lot of 45 and 90 degree aligned features, and not much else. This takes a lot away from the quality of your project, for not very good reason because it's very easy to use other noise instead.

Take any tutorial that tells you to use Mathf.PerlinNoise, or Perlin noise in general, with a grain of salt. Unity is probably causing more problems than it solves by including Mathf.PerlinNoise without any Mathf.SimplexNoise or documentation to steer developers to the latter, but that's a separate issue that warrants its own discussion.

I would do one of the following:

1. Import Unity.Mathematics and use Unity.Mathematics.noise.snoise(float2) for noise.
2. Import FastNoiseLite (I contributed to this repo) and use one of the "Simplex" noise options. https://github.com/Auburn/FastNoise

Both of these should fix your problem, as well as increase the quality of your terrain.